# How to Hide or remove New button on case Object for particular profile in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

Need to restrict by creating cases for a few profile users. The new button should not be visible or hide for a particular profile user in lightning experience. How to do this? Is there any configuration change or can we do it by overriding New Button?

[image]

Comment: Do you want the access in Classic?

Comment: No. In Classic also we no need access

Answer (score 1):

In the user's profile, remove the `Create` access for Case object and system will automatically hide it.

Edit based on comments:

Since, the button cannot be restricted based on profiles, so better to handle that with validation rule so, only specific profiles can create cases and others not.

Comment: @Boral, I have tried this, but few functionalities are breaking through code as we have lots of Apex classes on CASE object. Any other idea please?